# How to map a many-to-many linking table to use another schema?

Tags: nhibernate, attributes, nhibernate-mapping

I have a few classes that I map to non-default schema using NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes like this:

```
[Class(Lazy = true, Schema = "NonDefaultSchemaName")]
public class Class1
```

I also have some many-to-many mappings:

```
[Set(Inverse = false, Table = "Class1ToClass2", Lazy = true, Cascade = "none")]
[Key(1, Column = "Class1ID")]
[ManyToMany(2, ClassType = typeof(Class2), Column = "Class2ID")]
```

What I am trying to achieve is to have the linking table Cass1ToClass2 mapped to

```
[NonDefaultSchemaName].[Class1ToClass2]
```

NHibernate automatically maps to the default schema. I could not find anything similar googling around...

Answer (score 1):

should be possible now using

```
[Set(Inverse = false, Table = "Class1ToClass2", Schema = "Schema", Lazy = true, Cascade = "none")]
```

Comment: sorry, not working on that project any more and can't check. So I can't mark your answer as accepted.